# fopen() returns NULL while running program from Comand Line

Tags: c, command-line, permissions, fopen, null-pointer

Any of my C programmes utilizing fopen() run perfectly from IDE or Windows environment, but fail when opened from Command Line (cmd.exe), as fopen("r") keeps returning NULL pointer. The files do exist and have no permission restrictions. So the programms DO run from Command Line, but with error (null pointer) as soon as they encounter fopen() in the code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  FILE *fr, *fw;
  int j;

  if(argc==1)
   {
     vypis_navodu(argv[0]); // function call
   }

  if(argc==2)
   {     
      if ((fr=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) // returns NULL from CMD 
          {
           printf("\nunable to open %s\n", argv[1]); 
           return 1;    
          }
```

SOLUTION USING THE FULL PATH TO FILE:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fr, *fw;
char path[100] = "C:\\folder\\"; // path to the folder
int j;

if(argc==1)
 {
  vypis_navodu(argv[0]);
 }


if(argc==2)
 {   
    if ((fr=fopen(strcat(path, argv[1]), "r")) == NULL) // works o.k.
      {
        printf("\nunable to open %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;   
      }
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Try to use a full pathname with fopen()

Comment: Use strerror (http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/strerror.3.html) to display the error message in order to know what's wrong. You can use perror too, or simply errno value.

Comment: There is no problem in the snippet of code you have posted. You should also share the  argument set in IDE to pass when program run and argument that you are passing in command line.

Comment: @H.S. the path i was passing in command line was not full. It works with the full path. Thanks.

Comment: Could you run `type filename.txt` or `cat filename.txt` or similar from the command prompt and see the file? If so, your program (`yourprog filename.txt`) should work, AFAIK.  If the `type` or `cat` operations fail, you need to pass a different relative or absolute filename that identifies the file you want the commands to work with.  Embedding a literal directory name in the program is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you so much, but none these two commands worked. However I managed to find a relative path that works with the original version of my program (myprogram relative-path). But "myprogram filename.txt" does not work anyway.

Embedding literal directory name worked for me as far as I could finally go on with the excercises in my textbook (since I was already desperate enough), but I do realize it may not be the most elegant (or not even the least elegant) way of solving problem.

Comment: The key part of my comment was "try a system-provided program with the filename you plan to pass to your program".  If the system command can read it, your program should be able to read the same file when the same name is provided on the command line.  If the system command can't read it, the chances are your program won't be able to either.  I'm glad you've got something that works adequately on your machine. Be aware that you may have issues if you need to hand in homework that will work on your instructor's testing machine. Normally, programs use the file names on the command line "as is".

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> The fopen(), fdopen(), and freopen() functions may also fail and
> set errno for any of the errors specified for the routine
> malloc(3).
>
> The fopen() function may also fail and set errno for any of the
> errors specified for the routine open(2).

You may use `perror` or `strerrror` to print out an error message.

> The perror() function produces a message on standard error
> describing the last error encountered during a call to a system
> or library function.

Here's an example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    /* argument checking here... */

    FILE *fp;

    errno = 0;
    fp = fopen(argv[1]), "r");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: [The `fopen()` function is not required to set `errno`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p9): "The fopen function returns a pointer to the object controlling the stream. If the open operation fails, fopen returns a null pointer."  That means [`fopen()` is free to modify `errno` to any non-zero value whether there's any error or not](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3): "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error. ..."  The question does not state the C implementation used, so the man page may not be relevant.

Comment: Note that the POSIX specification for [`fopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) stipulates: _Otherwise, a null pointer shall be returned, [CX] ⌦  and `errno` shall be set to indicate the error. ⌫_ where the material in "[CX] ⌦ …  ⌫" indicates an extension over standard C that does require `errno` to be set on POSIX systems.  Check the man page for `fopen()` on your system, but if it is Unix-based (Linux, etc), it will set `errno`.